# how to copy datagrid itemsource into observable collection object in silverlight5?

Tags: silverlight-5.0

I have a values in DataGrid like Name,Age,Address. I have to get datagrid values into Observable collection Object?Is it possible. .If Yes then plz anyone can tell me the solution?

Comment: I Mean that i created a List<Customer> object =new List();(Customer is my classname) and I append those values into DataGrid like CustomerDataGrid.ItemsSource=object;(CustomerDataGrid is DataGrid name) and I want to copy data from CustomerDataGrid into ObservableCollection object..Can any1 tell me?in silverlight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(sorry for my bad english)

Why you simply dont create a ObservableCollection in the first place instead of using a List?

Anyway, you can create an ObservableCollection with the List data this way:

```
ObservableCollection<Customer> customers = new ObservableCollection<Customer>(YOUR_LIST);
```

If you really need to get the data from the DataGrid ItemsSource:

```
ObservableCollection<Customer> customers = new ObservableCollection<Customer>(grid.ItemsSource as List<Customer>);
```